# In google sheets looking to set/update a timestamp on Sheet1 any time I import a CSV to replace Sheet2

Tags: csv, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've created a tool in Google Sheets to audit ticket pricing data in an external source to ensure the prices are accurate in our sales environment. The tool is working exactly as expected, but I'm hoping to get help with a quality of life improvement.

The way the audit tool works is Sheet1 has all of the expected pricing and is set up with a number of VLOOKUP functions to compare to Sheet2. Sheet2 gets updated by importing a CSV, each time the CSV is imported i use the "replace current sheet" option.

What I'm hoping to do is add a timestamp on Sheet1 that updates every time I import a new CSV in order to display when the data was last updated.

In doing google searches I've found a lot of was to do a timestamp on a cell update, but I'm hoping one of you brilliant folk have a way to capture the date/time information of when a cell is updated on another sheet.

I've yet to find any information that gets me moving in the correct direction on this ask, so I'm coming here.